# Unable to use std::bind with std::promise

Tags: c++, c++11, bind, future

If I use:

```
int a = 3;
std::function<void()> task1 = std::bind([](int a){}, std::move(a));
```

It's OK, but if I replace `int` with `std::promise<int>`:

```
std::promise<int> p;
std::function<void()> task2 = std::bind([](std::promise<int> p){}, std::move(p));
```

G++ throws an error:

```
error: conversion from ‘std::_Bind_helper<false, main()::__lambda7, std::promise<int> >::type {aka std::_Bind<main()::__lambda7(std::promise<int>)>}’ to non-scalar type ‘std::function<void()>’ requested
 std::function<void()> task2 = std::bind([](std::promise<int> p){}, std::move(p));
```

Why? What's the problem with binding a `std::promise` param?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `std::function` requires the internal type to be copyable. That property holds for the first example (`int`) but not for the second (`std::promise` is move only). Notice that if you don't use `std::function` and call the lambda directly, the code works fine:

```
std::bind([](std::promise<int>& p) { p.set_value(42); }, std::move(p))();
```

To use `std::function`, you need to wrap the promise into a wrapper of some kind. The standard `std::reference_wrapper` should suffice:

```
std::promise<int> p;
std::function<void()> foo = std::bind([](std::promise<int>& p) {}, std::ref(p));
foo();
```

You need to worry about the life time of the original `p` variable however. One other option is to pass the promise around managed inside a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: You are right. It seems `std::function` needs a copyable type. I will use `std::shared_ptr` instead. Thanks very much!